# How do I open a file with an .by2 extension?

Tags: binary, file-extension

I mean there is a service, which claims to do it for 189 bucks but there has to be a way.
I got the file by exporting my cards from brainyoo...
Any information on the file type would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks a lot

Opening it in any text editor or HTML editor only returned gibberish and i couldn't convince any other program to open it...

Answer (score 1):

You can open these types of files with [WinRAR](https://www.win-rar.com/start.html?&L=0).